# How to split text and get only array value by using shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

I am new to shell script. Can anyone show me the way to split text above. 
Here the value that I need, if really possible to store in array in shell script?

=============SAMPLE TEXT=====================

```
Reading application configuration data...


Beginning interaction for module default...
default: ['1', '52', '53', '54', 55-vm, '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61',
  '62', '63', '65', '66', '67', ah-builtin-python-bundle, export-backend, export,
  lab, stage-test, test]

Success.
Cleaning up temporary files for module default...
```

============================================

==============RESULT========================

```
  ['1', '52', '53', '54', 55-vm, '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61',
  '62', '63', '65', '66', '67', ah-builtin-python-bundle, export-backend, export,
  lab, stage-test, test]
```

============================================

Comment: to be honest, I am poor with shell script especially using with Regular expression. I also have tried some by searching on some site, but still can not help! Let's me try yours then Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started. But it will only extract arrays that are on a single line and it's good only if there is only one array per line.

```
ARRAYTXT=$(sed -nr 's/.*(\[.*\]).*/\1/p' file.txt)
ARRAY=($(echo $ARRAYTXT | sed -r "s/'([^']*)'/\1/g;s/([^,]*),/\1/g;s/\[//;s/\]//"))
echo ${a[*]}
```

result:

```
1 52 53 54 55-vm 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 65 66 67 ah-builtin-python-bundle export-backend export lab stage-test test
```

Comment: It's seem not work then. Here the comment that I have try           $sed -nr 's/.*(\[.*\]).*/\1/p' ./text

Comment: here other one  $cat ./text | sed -nr 's/.*(\[.*\]).*/\1/p'

Comment: what doesn't work about it? Is the array on a single line or on multiple lines? It's not clear from your example.

Comment: Oh sorry it's my mistake. It's work now! Thank you very much. But if I like the result to store in array because I will use it for some next logic. Can you help me for that ?

Answer (score 1):

I use awk to transform the data, and store it in an array

```
ary=( $( 
    awk -v RS= '
        match($0, /default: \[(.+)\]/, a) { gsub(/[\n,]/,"",a[1]); print a[1] }
    ' sample.txt
) )
```

And verify the contents of the array:

```
$ for i in "${!ary[@]}"; do echo "$i  ${ary[i]}"; done
0  '1'
1  '52'
2  '53'
3  '54'
4  55-vm
5  '55'
6  '56'
7  '57'
8  '58'
9  '59'
10  '60'
11  '61'
12  '62'
13  '63'
14  '65'
15  '66'
16  '67'
17  ah-builtin-python-bundle
18  export-backend
19  export
20  lab
21  stage-test
22  test
```

Comment: Wow great! It's such a best help! Thanks you!

Comment: HI! May you do me a favor! when I use abov code with one line (in terminal) it's work fine, but when I put in to the shell script it's display "Syntax error: "(" unexpected"!

Comment: arrays are a bash feature. make sure your script is **not** `#!/bin/sh`